# Regex: Match string (including nested characters) inside 2 characters) while not capturing characters, but non-greedy

Tags: python, regex, ply

I'm done making a markup language, but I'm now making optimized strings for it.
I want there to be nested characters allowed inside the strings, with my RPLY lexer there are 3 objects I need to allow inside of strings (curly braces and backticks), as well as not capturing the characters, such as the regex code I've tried:

```regex
(?:`)+([\w\W]+)(?:`)+
```

But this is greedy, and will only match between the first grave it sees and the last, as well as creating non-captured groups that are unsupported with RPLY.
Is there an alternative to this that's non-greedy but will allow nested characters? (and no non-capturing groups please, I'm using the the RPython distribution of PLY (RPLY) lexer and parser which doesn't support regex groups)

If anybody needs more code, I have 2 Python classes, both for the lexer and parser.

**LEXER**

```py
from rply import LexerGenerator


class BMLLexer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__lexer = LexerGenerator()

    def __add_tokens(self):
        # Statement definitions
        # Note that I need both the OPEN_STATEMENT and CLOSE_STATEMENT to be allowed inside the string.
        self.__lexer.add('OPEN_STATEMENT', r'\{')
        self.__lexer.add('CLOSE_STATEMENT', r'\}')

        # Basic things
        # Note that RPLY's parser doesn't allow multiple groups (includes capturing and non-capturing), so the only option would be just to use functions to remove the first and last backtick from the string, or find something in regex that allows me to automatically get rid of the first and last backtick in the string.
        self.__lexer.add('STRING', r'(?:`)+([\w\W]+)(?:`)+')
        
        # Ignore spaces
        self.__lexer.ignore('\s+')

    def build(self):
        self.__add_tokens()
        return self.__lexer.build()
```

**PARSER**

```py
import re
from bmls.language.parser.definitions import BMLDefinitionCapped, BMLDefinitionSingle
from rply import ParserGenerator, Token

class BMLParser():
    """The direct BML parser.

    Raises:
        SyntaxError: If given invalid syntax, the parser will throw a SyntaxError.
    """
    # Init parser
    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes the parser.
        """
        self.pg = ParserGenerator(
            # A list of all token names accepted by the parser.
            [
                'OPEN_STATEMENT',
                'CLOSE_STATEMENT',

                'STRING',
            ],

            precedence= [
                ('left', ['OPEN_STATEMENT']),

                ('left', ['STRING']),

                ('right', ['CLOSE_STATEMENT'])
            ]
        )



    # Parsing

    def parse(self):
        """Parses BML content

        Raises:
            SyntaxError: If given invalid syntax, the parser will throw a SyntaxError.

        Returns:
            list: An HTML/XML formatted list of items.
        """

        # Multi-expression handling
        @self.pg.production('main : expr')
        @self.pg.production('main : main expr')
        def main(p):
            if len(p) == 1:
                return p
            else:
                for x in p[1:]:
                    p[0].append(x)
                return p[0]



        # Expression handling

        @self.pg.production('expr : STRING OPEN_STATEMENT main CLOSE_STATEMENT')
        def definition_capped(p):
            name = self.__toSTRING(p[0])
            definition1 = self.__toSTRING(p[2])

            comp = BMLDefinitionCapped(name, definition1)

            return self.__toHTML(comp)

        @self.pg.production('expr : OPEN_STATEMENT STRING CLOSE_STATEMENT')
        def definition_uncapped(p):
            name = self.__toSTRING(p[1])

            comp = BMLDefinitionSingle(name)
            return self.__toHTML(comp)



        # Expression types
        # This is where the string is parsed, currently using the function __removeFIrstLast. I wish to replace this with a supported expression.
        @self.pg.production('expr : STRING')
        def string_expr(p):
            if p[0].gettokentype() == 'STRING':
                return self.__removeFirstLast(self.__toSTRING(p[0]), '`', '`')



        # Error handling

        @self.pg.error
        def error_handle(token):
            raise SyntaxError('Error on Token (\'' + token.gettokentype() + '\' , \'' + token.getstr() + '\')')




    # Public utilities

    def build(self):
        return self.pg.build()



    # Private utilities

    def __removeFirstLast(self, tok, char, endchar):
        if isinstance(tok, str):
            if tok.startswith(char) and tok.endswith(endchar):
                return re.sub(r'^' + char + r'|' + endchar + r'$', '', tok)
            else:
                return tok
        else:
            return tok

    def __toHTML(self, tok):
        output = ''

        if isinstance(tok, BMLDefinitionCapped):
            right = ''
            try:
                for k1 in tok.right:
                    right += k1
            except:
                right += tok.right
            output += '<' + tok.left + '>' + right + '</' + tok.left.split(' ')[0] + '>'
        elif isinstance(tok, BMLDefinitionSingle):
            output += '<' + tok.left + '>'
        elif isinstance(tok, Token):
            output += tok.getstr()
        else:
            output += tok

        return output

    def __toSTRING(self, tok):
        if isinstance(tok, Token):
            return tok.getstr()
        else:
            return tok

    def __toINT(self, tok):
        if isinstance(tok, Token):
            return int(tok.getstr())
        else:
            return int(tok)
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace `[\w\W]` with `[^\`]` ?

Comment: I did forget to include another part (woops) - I don't want to have to rely on removing the first and last characters from every string, and I would like regex to do it if that's possible. Thanks for the answer for the first part though, that was helpful and worked.

Comment: And how would I "not" match with multiple characters such as `, {, and } in the same character class?

Comment: You don't mention `{` and `}` anywhere in your question, so now I really don't know what your needs are. Please try to make your requirements more explicit by specifying exactly what you expect the regex to match. (Please note that it's impossible to next unisex delimiters like backtick; since there's no way to distinguish between a close tick and a "nested" open tick. Matching nested braces is possible, of course, but it can't be done with a standard regex.)

Comment: I'm editing the post to be more applicable.  
Also it seems as since I have a keyboard that only supports this kind of grave accent (`), it seems to work with everything I've tried. Would there be a viable alternative to this? I'm considering using square brackets, even though ```\[+([^\[\]]+)\]+``` doesn't work for nested brackets.
And what regex flavor should I use if I Python's doesn't work and RPLY only supports the Python default flavor?

Comment: If you're using a keyboard with composing grave accents (like the Spanish keyboard I use) then you probably type a backtick by pressing the grave accent key twice (grave+a: à; grave+grave: `). That will give you the character whose character code is 0x60, i.e. what someone else might get by hitting the backtick key.

Comment: My question is: will you accept an answer using Ply? Or do you insist on RPly? (Your question was tagged [tag:ply], and that's what I use and have installed :-) ).

Comment: Another question: Since I'm still uncertain what you are trying to do, and your code doesn't really help, could you please include either a complete description of the syntax you're trying to parse, or at least a complex example with the expected tokenization? The more precise you can be, the better.

Comment: Yes, I would accept an answer using PLY, as RPLY is just a port to RPython.  

I'm trying to make a string that can allow the other two tokens, ```CLOSE_STATEMENT``` and ```OPEN_STATEMENT``` inside of the string. Currently this throws an error because they're being found in strings, but not abiding by the regex rules I set.

This is the syntax: ```    \`h1\` { \`Hello, World!\` }    ```, and ```    { \`!DOCTYPE html\` }    ```.

Sorry I'm responding late, I got a stomach bug and I've been feeling really sick lately. Hope you understand.